# Asignarle variable int[] values

Tags: c#

Estoy usando este método, estoy teniendo dificulta.

> int[] ReadWriteMultipleRegisters(int startingAddressRead, int
>   quantityRead, int startingAddressWrite, int[] values)
>
> Read/Write Multiple Registers (Function code 23).
>
> startingAddressRead:  First input register to read.
>
> quantityRead:  Number of input registers to read.
>
> startingAddressWrite:  First input register to write.
>
> values: Values to write.
>
> returns:  Int Array which contains the holding registers
>   [0..quantityRead-1].

Estoy teniendo un error al asignarle la `variable int[] values`, me podrían ayudar.

Gracias.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EasyModbus;

namespace comunicacion_tcp
{
    class Program
    {
        private string IpAddress = "192.168.178.111";
        private int port = 502;
        private ushort startAddres = 4352;
        private ushort quantity = 1;
        private ushort startAddres1 = 4353;
        private int writeData;
        private ModbusClient modbustcp;
        public Program()
        {
            modbustcp = new ModbusClient(IpAddress, port);
            modbustcp.Connect();
            int[] response = modbustcp.ReadWriteMultipleRegisters( startAddres,quantity, startAddres1 , writeData);
            modbustcp.Disconnect();
            Console.WriteLine("value of input register 1" + response[0].ToString());


        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program _program = new Program();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nos ayudarias si agregas el error que te marca amigo.

Comment: Tienes que declarar la variable `writerData` asi: `private int[] writeData;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cómo dice [alanfcm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/81482/alanfcm) en los comentarios, estas declarando mal la variable `writeData`, tu función espera un `int[]` y vos le mandas un `int`

```
//Declaración de variables
int startingAddressRead = 0, quantityRead = 0, startingAddressWrite = 0;
int[] values = new int[5];
//Llamada a la función y almacenado el retorno en 'resultado'
var resultado = ReadWriteMultipleRegisters(startingAddressRead, quantityRead, startingAddressWrite, values);

//Función de ejemplo
int[] ReadWriteMultipleRegisters(int startingAddressRead, int quantityRead, int startingAddressWrite, int[] values) => new int[2];
```

Como se ve en el fragmento de código no deberías tener ningun problema para llamar a tu función.

Saludos!

Comment: Se quita el error de asignación  de la variable writeData ( Error:cannot convert from int to int[] )
 Me presenta un error 'Starting address invalid or starting address + quantity invalid'

   Cuando ejecuto el programa,  estoy un poco crudo en esto disculpen.

Comment: Te recomiendo, que si esta respuesta solucionó la duda que planteaste originalmente, la marques como correcta e inicies una nueva pregunta, con el nuevo problema, de modo que otras personas puedan usar las preguntas y respuestas de StackOverflow!